# Can't find any collection named 'fabfile

Tags: google-colaboratory, fabric

*Python fabric module is instaled* and I have fabfile_ippbx.py file everythink is instaled.
Commend:

```
root@rd:/home/pi/apps# fab -f fabfile_ippbx.py main_task
```

Output:

```
Can't find any collection named 'fabfile'!
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I use python 3.7, just uninstall:

```
pip3 uninstall fabric
pip3 install fabric
```

And it works.